# Hibernate entity extending base class, table formed for the entity doesn't have columns for attributes in base class

Tags: java, hibernate

```
public class BaseEntity {

  @Column
  private String author;

  public BaseEntity(String author) {
      this.author = author;
  }

  public String getAuthor() {
      return author;
  }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book extends BaseEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
  private long bookId;

  @Column
  private String title;

  public Book(String author, String title) {
    super(author);
    this.title = title;
  }

  public Book() {
    super("default");
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }
}
```

My sql table have just two columns, bookId and title. What should I do to get table for all the three members including author.

My sql table have just two columns, bookId and title. What should I do to get table for all the three members including author.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should add `@MappedSuperclass` annotation to the `BaseEntity`

```
@MappedSuperclass 
public class BaseEntity {

  @Column
  private String author;

  public BaseEntity(String author) {
      this.author = author;
  }

  public String getAuthor() {
      return author;
  }

}
```