# JPA Inheritance : DB design where each row in one table corresponds to a table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jpa, inheritance, database-design

There is a table called Product(id, name). Each row in Product is a different kind of product. Every product has different information data. For example : Product like 'Internet' will have information data 'Current Plan', 'Account Number', 'Account Status' and so on. Whereas, a product like 'Insurance' will have information data 'Payee', 'Beneficiary', 'Total Deposits', 'Total Claims' and so on.
There is another table called Customer like this.

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  first_name text NOT NULL,
  last_name text NOT NULL,
  street_add text NOT NULL,
  city text NOT NULL,
  state text NOT NULL,
  zip text NOT NULL,
  phone text NOT NULL,
  ssn text,
  customer_since timestamp without time zone,
  product_id integer NOT NULL,
  intro_audio text NOT NULL,
  search_params text,
  verification_params text,
  CONSTRAINT customer_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_product_id FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
      REFERENCES product (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I want to create a table for each product:
For example for internet :

```
CREATE TABLE internet_product_info
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  customer_id integer NOT NULL,
  current_plan text NOT NULL,
  acc_type text NOT NULL,
  acc_no text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT internet_product_info_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_customer_id FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
      REFERENCES customer(id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

For insurance :

```
CREATE TABLE insurance_product_info
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  customer_id integer NOT NULL,
  payee text NOT NULL,
  beneficiary text NOT NULL,
  total_deposits integer NOT NULL, 
  total_claims integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT insurance_product_info_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_customer_id FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
      REFERENCES customer(id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I want to ask if this is a right approach to go for such scenarios or there is some better options available.

In java, I will retrieve product properties like :

```
public class Customer implements Serializable{  
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName; 
    private String streetAdd;
    private String city; 
    private String state; 
    private String zip; 
    private String phone; 
    private String ssn; 
    private Date customerSince; 
    private Object internetProdInfo;
    private Product product;    
}

if(customer.getInternetProdInfo() instanceOf InternetProdInfo){
 /* get the info for it*/
}
```

Also, how can I dynamically load these product specific fields on jsp page dynamically.

Comment: `CONSTRAINT fk_product_id FOREIGN KEY (product_id)` the column `product_id` does not exist. There is a column `sim_product_id` (and I *think* it should not exist, either)

Comment: I renamed sim_product_id  to product_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use java Inheritance in Hibernate as You have mentioned here.
`if(customer.getInternetProdInfo() instanceOf InternetProdInfo){
     /* get the info for it*/
    }`
here we can have few links you can go through it not a simple solution it has its own sides, and many more are there.

1. [Documentation If You have Plenty of Time](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html)
2. [Blog Short and Helpful](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-entity-inheritance-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)
3. [Another Blog Short and Helpful](https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/mapping-inheritance-in-hibernate)
4. [A Helpful Question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/264796/programmatically-extending-hibernate-table-entity-definitions-in-spring-how)
5. [Another  Helpful Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957228/extending-hibernate-entities-with-annotation)
6. [https://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143354/hibernate-entity-extending-base-class-table-formed-for-the-entity-doesnt-have)
7. [Another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609526/hibernate-extend-entity-for-same-table)
8. [Another Short Doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html)

   a mapped superclass has no separate table defined for it(Use  `@MappedSuperclass`).

   mapping information may be overridden in such subclasses by using the `@AttributeOverride` and `@AssociationOverride` annotations or corresponding XML elements